# SingleValueContainer error thrown during unit tests - retrieving records

Tags: sqlite.swift

I am a bit confused why I am getting this error thrown while trying to read from the database.  In my test, I write the record successfully.  Immediately after the write, I am trying to read the records in the database and have the error "decoding a single value container is not supported".

The Codable object is this:

```
struct AddressTypeTwo: Codable {

    // MARK: CRUD
    
    var id: Int?
    var created: Date?
    var createdBy: String?
    var modified: Date?
    var modifiedBy: String?
    var deleted: Date?
    var deletedBy: String?
    
    var name: String?
    var companyId: Int?
    
    // MARK: CodingKeys
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, created, createdBy, modified, modifiedBy
        case deleted, deletedBy

        case name
        case companyId = "company_id"
    }
}
```

The insert works fine:

```
    func insert(toBeInserted obj: Codable) -> Int {
        
        if let newId = try? DbSupport.shared.activeDatabase?.run(table.insert(obj)) {
            return Int(newId)
        }
        
        return -1
    }
```

I am using this function to retrieve all records - and this is where I get the error:

```
    func get<T: Codable>(_ includeDeleted: Bool = false) -> [T]? {
        
        var query = table.filter(tableDeleted == nil)
        if includeDeleted {
            query = table
        }
        
        guard let database = DbSupport.shared.activeDatabase else { return nil }
        
        // these always come back in an array even though there is an id
        let addresses: [T?]? = try? database.prepare(query).map { row in
            if let rowData: T = try? row.decode() {
                return rowData
            }
            return nil
        }
        
        return addresses?.compactMap { $0 }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the table definition?

Comment: id INTEGER 
created DATETIME 
created_by TEXT
modified DATETIME
modified_by TEXT
deleted DATETIME
deleted_by TEXT
name TEXT
company_id INTEGER

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your DATETIME fields to TEXT. SQLite.swift maps Date objects to Text

Comment: That isn't work :(. Thanks for the idea.